# Ругается валидатор

Tags: html, валидация

[image: Валидатор ругается]

---

Валидатор ругается и выдаетт эту ошибку, с чем это связанно и как это исправить?

[image]

Comment: С тем, что вы написали `<html>` там где нельзя его писать

Comment: а где тогда его писать ? Я только начал изучать просто html, мало чего знаю, можете объяснить пожалуйста

Comment: На вашем скриншоте видно, что вы перед `<html>` что-то другое написали, но так нельзя, `<html>` всегда должен быть самым первым после `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло, я добавил еще одну ошибку, если не сложно, можете помочь с ней тоже

Answer (score 0):

Стандарт:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Моя первая страница</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```